# Formula/theory to detect the desired number of workshop topics

Tags: voting-theory

I need to prepare a workshop and at the end of the workshop I want participants to choose from a set of questions (e.g. n=20) only x (e.g. x=5) questions to discuss. Therefore I want to give each participant a number of points (red spots) to distribute to the whole selection of questions.

Question:
Is there a formula/theory that allows me to detect the right number of "voting points" that I have to give to each participant in order to find a limited number x of questions.

It would be great if anybody could help me!

Comment: Can you explain a little further? What I understood was: you want your students to do a test with $x$ questions. You suggest $n$ possible questions and have your students distribute $k$ red spots each through your suggestions. In the end, you'll submit the $x$ highest-scoring questions to all the students. You want to know if there exists an optimal $k$ for the task (where you do not exactly know the meaning of "optimal"). Am I right?

Comment: Exactly! I would like to know if there is a general formula I can use no matter what x, n, k. Hence, I want to know how many red dots (k) I have to distribute to my students if I want to get a specific amount of questions (n). That means out of my 20 posed questions, I finally want to have 5 questions we discuss according to their voting. Better?